# Displaying views outside superviews bounds

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

What I have in my app is a scroll view, and a series of pictures I want the user to swipe thru that are in the scroll view. I want all of them to be visible, but still have the pages be the width of one of the pictures. How can I do this? (Tell me if I need more detail)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To further @max's answer, you also will most likely want to set your scroll view's clipsToBounds property to NO.

Comment: ah this was it. Im not really up to speed on SO etiquette. whos answer should i accept?

Comment: Mine! :P. Seriously though, whatever you think is the correct answer. If the other answer not chosen (whether that be mine or not) was helpful give it an up vote :)

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly, you have to set the contentSize property to be as big, to fit all the images. And you have to set pagingEnabled = YES

So the frame size of your scroll would be equal to the size of the image, and content size would be the bounding rect for all the images frames.

Comment: the only problem with this is that then not all the images are visible

Comment: what do you mean? that's what scroll is made for - to show content that is not visible.

Comment: OK let me explain this a bit clearer. I have 4 images that are 250 pixels wide. I want my scroll view to page to each one, but display all of them. When you make the scroll view big enough to see all of them, it's page size increases. Make it the size of one, and you don't get to see the others. Anyway the person below gave some more info on this.

Comment: not sure it would help you much, cause the default value of clipsToBounds is already NO.

Answer (score 1):

You need to setup your UIScrollView frame to be the size of the pictures, then set the contentSize of the UIScrollView to be the width of the number of images * image width.  If you want each photo to "page" like in most apps, you would also need to set pagingEnabled to YES.  You also probably want to suppress the scroll indicators.

For example:

```
NSArray someArrayOfUIImageViews...
NSUInteger imageWidth = 100;

pageScroller = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,imageWidth,160)];
pageScroller.scrollEnabled = YES;
pageScroller.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
pageScroller.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;
pageScroller.pagingEnabled = YES;
pageScroller.contentSize = imageWidth * [someArrayOfUIImageViews count];
```

Then add the pageScroller to the parent view, then add each of the images to the pageScroller spreading them across the contentSize area...

```
for (UIImageView * someImageView in someArrayOfUIImageViews)
{
    CGFrame frame = someImageView.frame;
    frame.origin.x += frame.size.width;
    someImageView.frame = frame;
    [pageScroller addSubview:someImageView];
}
```